# Are there options that would boost the amount of memory that NuSMV can use during a specification run?

Tags: boost, formal-verification, model-checking, nusmv

During specification running  in nusmv, it takes  several hours and eventually gives the result of "killed 9". How to speed up the execution?
Are there options that would boost the amount of memory that NuSMV can use during a specification run?

Comment: It is possible that this may not fit your needs, but did you take a look at [FAQ#003](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/faq.html#003) on their website?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use nuXmv https://es-static.fbk.eu/tools/nuxmv/ which is the successor of NuSMV. It provides newer SAT-based model-checking algorithms that often use less memory than BDD-based ones, and it allows for the same model specifications as NuSMV.

Overall it depends on why NuSMV runs out of memory. Most of the time, it will not manage to get the model to build, which means you'll have to reduce your model size. For this you might want to look whether some state variables could become Boolean signals without state, or if you an reduce the range of some of the variables.

If you have a parametric model, e.g., where a variable number of modules is used or the bit width of some variables can be changed, you can try to get a simpler variant to run and then find out which part makes the memory demand grow. This part should then be modelled in a different way.